# Prepend two divs, the same counting in counter click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var divNumber = 1;
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
  $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="count" id="div' + divNumber + '" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>'));
  divNumber++;
});

var divNumber = 1;
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
  $('.Wrap').prepend($(' <div class="List"><div class="count" id="divList' + divNumber + '" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div></div></div>'));
  divNumber++;
});

function makeCount(id) {
  var count = parseInt($("#" + id).text());
  if (isNaN(count)) {
    count = 1; //For the first click
  } else {
    count++;
  }

  $("#" + id).text(count);
}

$(".GreyDiv").on("click", function() {
  $(".container").css({
    display: 'none'
  });
  $(".List").css({
    display: 'block'
  });
});
$(".RedDiv").on("click", function() {
  $(".container").css({
    display: 'block'
  });
  $(".List").css({
    display: 'none'
  });
});
```

```css
.Wrap {
  width: 650px;
  height: 800px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
}
.List {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.AddDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.GreyDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 170px;
}
.RedDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 250px;
}
.count {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="count" id="div0" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div>
  </div>
  <div class="List">
    <div class="count" id="divList0" onclick="makeCount(this.id);">My Counter</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="AddDiv">AddDiv</button>
<button class="GreyDiv">GreyDiv</button>
<button class="RedDiv">RedDiv</button>
```

Good morning,

I have two, little problems:

1. I would like click "My Counter" (text in white box) and start count (the same count) in GreyDiv (class="List") and RedDiv (class="count"), next click AddDiv and count anew, but separately from two previous divs.
2. When RedDiv is activ and click AddDiv will show GreyDiv, but I would like if active is GreyDiv show only new GreyDiv (RedDiv is added in the bacground), and when active is RedDiv show only new RedDiv (GreyDiv id added in the background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the result of this demo what you are looking for? I edited the id's of your counter div to have an '_'.

**UPDATED DEMO**

```js
var divNumber = 1;
var divCtrs = [0];
var red = 0; // initially red is closed;
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
  divCtrs[divNumber] = 0;
  // grey
  var $list = $('<div>', {
   class: 'List'
  }).append(
   $('<div>', {
     class: 'count',
        id   : 'divList_' + divNumber,
        text : 'My Counter'
    })
  );
  
  // red
  var $container =$('<div>', {
   class: 'container'
  }).append(
   $('<div>', {
     class: 'count',
        id   : 'div_' + divNumber++,
        text : 'My Counter'
    })
  );
  
  if (red) {
   $list.css('display', 'none');
    $container.css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $list.css('display', 'block');
    $container.css('display', 'none');
  }
  
  $('.Wrap').prepend($container, $list)
  
});


$(document).on('click','div[id^="div"]', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var ndx = parseInt(id.split('_')[1]);
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  if ($parent.hasClass('container')) {
    $parent.css({'background-color' : 'lightblue'});
  }
  if ($parent.hasClass('List')) {
    $parent.css({'background-color' : 'slategrey'});
  }        
  divCtrs[ndx]++;
  $('#div_' + ndx).text(divCtrs[ndx]);
  $('#divList_' + ndx).text(divCtrs[ndx]);
});

$(".GreyDiv").on("click", function() {
  red = 0;
  $(".container").css({
    display: 'none'
  });
  $(".List").css({
    display: 'block'
  });
});

$(".RedDiv").on("click", function() {
  red = 1;
  $(".container").css({
    display: 'block'
  });
  $(".List").css({
    display: 'none'
  });
});
```

```css
.Wrap {
  width: 650px;
  height: 800px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
}
.List {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.AddDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.GreyDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 170px;
}
.RedDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 250px;
}
.count {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="count" id="div_0">My Counter</div>
  </div>
  <div class="List">
    <div class="count" id="divList_0">My Counter</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="AddDiv">AddDiv</button>
<button class="GreyDiv">GreyDiv</button>
<button class="RedDiv">RedDiv</button>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: maybe you know also how solve this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516044/how-separate-counter-click/40517375#40517375 this next step your previous help :)

Comment: I actually made a new fiddle regarding your new problem

Comment: Good evening, I have one question, is possibilty click on "My counter" and change css style "container" or "list" ? (for example background-color), I tried add new id in container and next ++numberDiv in script but it doesn't work :(

Comment: So if I try to click on `Container's My Counter` it changes `Container's background-color`?

Comment: yes, I would like change color container's class after click My counter

Comment: Try to see the updated demo if it does what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was so close to do it oneself :) Thank you again! :)

Comment: If you will have any free time, you can look on this example, but this for my information (I am very excited to learn JavaScript, because this something new for me :)). I would like click on "Add Pop up" and class="OuterDiv" and change bacground-color in container (just like last time you did) and next click button HidePopUp and hide "OuterDiv" and background-color. I tried change 'div[id^="div"]' on '.AddPopUp' but doesn't work.  https://jsfiddle.net/kmbsvxwh/1/